# 'webgrid.Column(format:=)' syntax error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, webgrid

I'm new in `asp.net` so I'm following the 'Getting Started' tutorial from the asp web site but the tutorial is in `C#` and I'm using `VB` so I have to change the syntax but right now I'm on this [point](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/updating-data). My problem comes in the part of the code using to add the 'Edit' column, this the original code:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/EditMovie?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
    grid.Column("Title"),
    grid.Column("Genre"),
    grid.Column("Year")
))
```

And this is my code in `VB`:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle:="grid",
headerStyle:="head",
alternatingRowStyle:="alt",
columns:=grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(format:=@<a href="~/EditMovie?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
    grid.Column("Title"),
    grid.Column("Genre"),
    grid.Column("Year")
))
```

**The error comes in `format:=` but I don't know why**

In adition If someone knows where can I find the same tutorial but in `VB` it would be great.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad grammar.

**EDIT:** This is the error `Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected`

Comment: What error is being reported?

Comment: @ChicagoMike Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the syntax error was because in `VB` have to use double `@` like this:

```
grid.Column(format:=@@<a href="~/EditMovie?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Yes, that's a weird undocumented feature of Razor and vb.net.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot more documentation for c# than vb.